# why cant i get disk_read_error to print

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

```
[org 0x7c00]                  ; declares the origin to 0x7c00
mov bp, 0x7c00                ; move the memory adress 0x7c00 to the base pointer, CS:IP always points to physical address 0x07C00.
mov sp, bp                    ; move the base pointer to the stack pointer

Hello_World:                  ; declares the label of the hello World position
db 'Hello World!',0           ; declares the string Hello World!
mov bx, Hello_World           ; move Hello_World labels position to bx[16 bit]
call printstring              ; calls the printsctring function
printstring:                  ; declares position of printstring function
     mov ah, 0x0e              
     .loop:                    ; declares position of loop
     cmp [bx], byte 0         ; compares a size of 0 bytes to bx
     je .exit                 ; if the result is equal jump to exit
               mov al, [bx]   ; declares move value at bx to al.
               int 0x10       ; declares print
               inc bx         ; increment the bx as a for loop
               jmp .loop      ; jump to the for loop
.exit:                        ; labels position of exit
ret                           ; returns from read_disk to its call

mov [boot_disk], dl           ; moves dl contents to boot disk error
boot_disk:                    ; declares boot_disk position
          db 0                ; defines a byte of 0
                              ; boot disk should now store the disk number inside the defined byte
program_space equ 0x7e00      ; program space variable equates to 0x7e00. 
                              ; 0x7e00 is 512 bytes after 0x7c00 in memory
call read_disk                ; calls read_disk function position





read_disk:                    ; declares read_disk position

mov bx, program_space         ; moves the program space to bx
mov al, 5                     ; reads 4 sectors aka 2000 bytes, or 2 kilobytes
mov dl, [boot_disk]           ; moves the value of boot disk into dl
mov ch, 0x00                  ; moves cyclinder 0 of hard drive into ch
mov dh, 0x00                  ; moves cyclinder 0 of hard drive into dh
mov cl, 0x02                  ; Moves 2 cylinders to cl

int 0x13                      ; interrupt commands the bios to read the disk
jc disk_read_failed           ; jumps conditionaly to disk read failed
ret                           ; returns to position of call printstring

disk_read_error:              ; declares disk_read_error position
db 'disk read failed',0         ; defines byte as disk read failed
disk_read_failed:             ; declares the label of disk_read_failed position
mov bx, disk_read_error       ; moves disk_read_error to bx
call printstring              ; calls the printing of the bx within a for loop.
jmp $

jmp $                         ; declares infinite loop
times 510-($-$$) db 0         ; declares bootloader size as 510 bites
dw 0xaa55                     ; declares this as a bootloader and uses 2 bites
                              ; total bites = 512 bites = 2 bites + 510 bites
```

Comment: Just a quick glance and noticed you placed your 'Hello World' data right along side the code.  After the processor executes the 'mov sp,bp' instruction, it will interpret the 'Hello World' data bytes as instructions.  You must place the data somewhere outside of the execution stream.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing executable code and data **a lot**! What then happens is that the CPU tries its best to interpret your data as code, which of course it isn't and so you can see the strangest things happen... The best of these is a clean freeze, if you're lucky.

**The messages and the variables, along with their label(s), belong beneath the executable code. The subroutines you place directly above the data**.

---

> ```
> mov bp, 0x7C00
> mov sp, bp
> ```

In this simple code you don't need to setup the stack, for which you should also setup `SS` to be correct.

> ```
> mov bx, Hello_World
> call printstring
> ```

The BIOS.Teletype function that is used in the *printstring* subroutine expects the DisplayPage argument in `BH` and the (graphics) color in `BL`. You should never use `BX` to point to the message! Use `SI` or `DI` for this.

> ```
> call printstring              ; calls the printsctring function
> printstring:                  ; declares position of printstring function
> ```

The error that happens here is that after the `call` returns the code will erroneously **fall through** in the *printstring* subroutine and upon completion perform a `ret` based on a **non-existing** return address!

> ```
> mov al, 5           ; reads 4 sectors aka 2000 bytes, or 2 kilobytes
> ```

With the value **5**, you will be reading 5 sectors of 512 bytes, totaling 2560 bytes. Using **4**, you will read 2KB or 2048 bytes.

---

What your code is missing, is setting up the `DS` and `ES` segment registers. You need a correct `DS` to address the messages and the variable, and you need a correct `ES` because the BIOS.ReadSectors function requires it. Incidentally, you forgot to mention the function number in `AH`.

This is a cleaned-up version of the code:

```
program_space equ 0x7E00

[org 0x7C00]

  xor  ax, ax
  mov  ds, ax
  mov  es, ax

  mov  [boot_disk], dl

  mov  di, Hello_World
  call printstring

  call read_disk

  jmp $

; ---------------------------- SUBROUTINES ---

printstring:
  mov  bx, 7                  ; BH=0 DisplayPage, BL=7 Color White
.loop:
  mov  al, [di]
  cmp  al, 0
  je   .exit
  mov  ah, 0x0E               ; BIOS.Teletype
  int  0x10
  inc  di
  jmp  .loop
.exit:
  ret

; ----------------------------

read_disk:
  mov  dh, 0                  ; DH=0 Head
  mov  dl, [boot_disk]
  mov  cx, 0x0002             ; CH=0 Cylinder, CL=2 SectorNumber
  mov  bx, program_space      ; ES:BX
  mov  ax, 0x0204             ; AH=2 FunctionNumber, AL=4 NumberOfSectors
  int  0x13
  jc   disk_read_failed
  ret
disk_read_failed:
  mov  di, disk_read_error
  call printstring
  jmp  $

; ---------------------------- DATA ---

Hello_World:      db 'Hello World!', 0
disk_read_error:  db 'disk read failed', 0
boot_disk:        db 0

; ----------------------------

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```