# keep getting reoccurring smiley faces on bootloader hello world program

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

Hi keep having this issue where I keep on getting reoccurring smiley faces. My work is across 2 files.

The first is the background bootloader and everything there works great and hasn't been changed but the second file is support to be a hello world but just produces recurring smiley faces.

```
program_space equ 0x7e00                          ; program space variable equates to 0x7e00. 
                                                  ; 0x7e00 is 512 bytes after 0x7c00 in memory  
[org 0x7c00]                                      ; declares the origin at the location 0x7c00
                                                  ; disk number is stored in al register
mov bp, 0x7c00                                    ; moves 0x7c00 to the base pointer, CS:IP 
                                                  ; CS:IP always points to physical address 0x07C00.
mov sp, bp                                        ; moves the base pointer bp to the stack pointer sp
; the basic_input_output_system(bios) automatically stores the disk number that the program was loaded from into the dl register
mov [boot_disk], dl                               ; moves dl contents to boot disk
mov al, [program_space]                           ; moves the program space to al

mov ah, 0x0e                                      ; BIOS.Teletype
mov al, '1'                                       ; Moves '1' to al register
int 0x10                                          ; calls print
mov al, ' '                                       ; Moves ' ' to al register
int 0x10                                          ; calls print
mov bx, Hello_World                               ; move Hello_World labels position to bx[16 bit]
call print_string                                 ; calls print_string function

mov ah, 0x0e                                      ; BIOS.Teletype
mov al,  0xa                                      ; move down 1 line.
int 0x10                                          ; print al
mov al,  0xd                                      ; move position to start of line.
int 0x10                                          ; print al
call read_disk                                    ; calls read_disk function position
mov bx, disk_read_true                            ; moves disk_read_true to bx register
call print_string                                 ; calls print_string function 
jmp program_space                                 ; jumps to program_space
jmp $                                             ; declares an infinite loop

print_string:                                     ; declares the label location of print_string function
push ax                                           ; pushes the ax register
push bx                                           ; pushes the bx register
mov ah, 0x0e                                      ; BIOS.Teletype
     .loop:                                       ; declares the label location of loop
     cmp [bx], byte 0                             ; compares a size of 0 bytes to bx register
     je .exit                                     ; if equal jump to .exit label
               mov al, [bx]                       ; moves bx contents to al register
               int 0x10                           ; declares print
               inc bx                             ; increment the bx register
               jmp .loop                          ; jump to .loop to create a for loop
.exit:                                            ; declares the label location of exit
pop ax                                            ; pops the ax register
pop bx                                            ; pops the bx register
ret                                               ; returns to position to call print_string

read_disk:                                        ; declares read_disk position
mov ah, 0x02                                      ; moves bios read sectors into memory to ah
mov bx, program_space                             ; moves the program space to bx
mov al, 4                                         ; reads 4 sectors aka 2000 bytes, or 2 kilobytes
mov dl, [boot_disk]                               ; moves the value of boot disk into dl
mov ch, 0x00                                      ; moves cyclinder 0 of hard drive into ch
mov dh, 0x00                                      ; moves cyclinder 0 of hard drive into dh
mov cl, 0x02                                      ; Moves 2 cylinders to cl
int 0x13                                          ; interrupt commands the bios to read the disk
jc disk_read_false                                ; jumps conditionaly to disk read false
ret                                               ; returns from read_disk to its call
disk_read_false:                                  ; declares the disk_read_false location
mov bx, disk_read_error                           ; moves the disk read error label to bx register
call print_string                                 ; declares a call to the print_string function
jmp $                                             ; declares infinite loop

Hello_World:        db 'Hello World!',0           ; declares the hello World position and the string Hello World!
disk_read_error:    db 'Disk Read = False;',0     ; declares disk_read_error position
disk_read_true:     db 'Disk Read = True;',0      ; declares the disk_read_true position
boot_disk:          db 0                          ; declares boot_disk position defines a bite of 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0           ; fills the drive with 510 bytes of ($-$$).
                                ; each ($-$$) is a double byte of 0. 
                                ; that makes up 510/512 bytes for the bootloader 
dw 0xaa55                       ; declares a bootloader using a double word occupying 2/512 bytes 
                                ; total is 512/512 bytes = 2/512 bytes + 510/512 bytes
```

This is the file below with the problem

```
                                                  ; Ralf Brown's Interrupt List
[org 0x7e00]                                      ; program space variable equates to 0x7e00. 
                                                  ; 0x7e00 is 512 bytes after 0x7c00 in memory 
mov ah, 0x0e                                      ; BIOS.Teletype
mov al,  0xa                                      ; **move down 1 line.**
int 0x10                                          ; **declares print**
mov al,  0xd                                      ; **move position to start of line.**
int 0x10                                          ; **declares print**
mov bx, extended_space_true
call print_string

jmp activate_protected_mode

activate_protected_mode:
call activate_A20
cli
lgdt [g.d.t_descriptor]
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 1
mov cr0, eax
jmp codeseg:protected_mode_start

activate_A20:
in al, 0x92
or al, 2
out 0x92, al
ret

[bits 32]

protected_mode_start:
mov ax, dataseg
mov ds, ax
mov ss, ax
mov es, ax
mov fs, ax
mov gs, ax
mov ebp, 90000
mov esp, ebp
mov [0xb8000], byte 'H'
mov [0xb8002], byte 'e'
mov [0xb8004], byte 'l'
mov [0xb8006], byte 'l'
mov [0xb8008], byte 'o'
mov [0xb800a], byte ' '
mov [0xb800c], byte 'W'
mov [0xb800e], byte 'o'
mov [0xb8010], byte 'r'
mov [0xb8012], byte 'l'
mov [0xb8014], byte 'd'
mov [0xb8016], byte '!'
jmp $


g.d.t.asm:
g.d.t_null_descriptor:
dd 0
dd 0
g.d.t_code_descriptor:                           ; **declares g.d.t_code_descriptor location**
dw 0xffff                                        ; **limit**
dw 0x0000                                        ; **limit base(low)**
db 0x00                                          ; **Base (medium)**
db 10011010b                                     ; **flags**
db 11001111b                                     ; **flags + upper limit**
db 0x00                                          ; **base (high)**

g.d.t_data_descriptor:                           ; **declares g.d.t_data_descriptor location**
dw 0xffff                                        ; **limit**
dw 0x0000                                        ; **limit base(low)**
db 0x00                                          ; **Base (medium)**
db 10010010b                                     ; **flags**
db 11001111b                                     ; **flags + upper limit**
db 0x00                                          ; **base (high)**

g.d.t_end:

g.d.t_descriptor:
g.d.t_size: 
dw g.d.t_end - g.d.t_null_descriptor - 1
dd g.d.t_null_descriptor

codeseg equ g.d.t_code_descriptor - g.d.t_null_descriptor
dataseg equ g.d.t_data_descriptor - g.d.t_null_descriptor

print_string:                                     ; **declares position of print_string function**
push ax                                           ; **pushes the ax register**
push bx                                           ; **pushes the bx register**
mov ah, 0x0e                                      ; **BIOS.Teletype**
.loop:                                            ; **declares position of loop**
cmp [bx], byte 0                                  ; **compares a size of 0 bytes to bx**
je .exit                                          ; **if the result is equal jump to exit**
mov al, [bx]                                      ; **declares move value at bx to al.**
int 0x10                                          ; **declares print**
inc bx                                            ; **increment the bx as a for loop**
jmp .loop                                         ; **jump to the for loop**
.exit:                                            ; **labels position of exit**
pop ax                                            ; **pops the ax register**
pop bx                                            ; **pops the bx register**
ret                                               **; returns to position of call printstring**


extended_space_true: db 'Extended Space = True;',0
times 2048-($-$$) db 0
```

**my explanations of the code are on the sides**

Comment: Please take the tour and not spam 30 times "please help me" this is just rude and will not increase the probability you get any answer

Comment: As @Björn pointed out, please take a look at the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and also review the section on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

> The first is the background bootloader and everything there works great and hasn't been changed

To you, the code in the first stage bootloader seems to work fine, but it still contains too many errors! As I explained in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68424214/why-cant-i-get-disk-read-error-to-print) you need to setup the segment registers yourself for correct operation of the code. Never trust pre-existing values! The only exception is the `DL` register that contains the code for the BootDrive.

```
mov  bp, 0x7C00
xor  ax, ax
mov  ds, ax
mov  es, ax
mov  ss, ax  \ Always keep these together and in this order, not kidding!
mov  sp, bp  /
```

And I will not repeat what I wrote in my previous answer, but I can say that if you would have adopted my version of the *print_string* subroutine (and thus use the BIOS.Teletype function like it should), you would not today show a code that restores the registers (that were pushed on the stack) in the wrong order. The stack is LIFO (LastInFirstOut), so the correct way is:

```
print_string:
  push ax        \
  push bx  \     |
  ...      | BX  | AX
  pop  bx  /     |
  pop  ax        /
  ret
```

> but the second file is support to be a hello world but just produces recurring smiley faces.

In accordance with my previous answer, you have placed the *print_string* subroutine near the bottom of the program. That's fine, except that this particular subroutine will get called from real address mode code and so must be using the 16-bit encoding. Sadly, because of the `[bits 32]` directive, NASM will still be using the 32-bit encoding when it arrives at that subroutine.
Two ways to solve this:

- either move this *print_string* subroutine right above the `[bits 32]` line
- or leave it where it is and tag it with an explicit `[bits 16]`

  ```
    [bits 16]
    print_string:
      push ax
      ...
  ```

This should resolve the problem of printing garbage characters before going into protected mode. Please take it one step at a time, and make sure that this part works truly fine before attempting to go into protected mode.